# Translate fields programmatically according to a specific Locale in Android

Tags: android, localization, locale

I want to create an android translation app, min api 15, max api 28. 
I created a simple interface that contains some TextViews, EditTexts andButtons. 
I want to translate the text of all fields from English to French for example. This interface contains a button when we click on, an custom alert dialog appear, that contains a confirm text "Yes" or a cancel text "cancel". My goal is when I click yes the translation to a certain language (French in my case) should be performed programmatically.

The following code is my mainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "";
    @BindView(R.id.changeLanguageButton)
    Button changeLanguage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LoadLocale();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        changeLanguage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //DIALOG ALERT
            new SweetAlertDialog(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitleText(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.dialog_default_title))
                    .setConfirmText(getString(R.string.confirm))
                    .setConfirmClickListener(sweetAlertDialog -> {
                        Log.i(TAG,"test");
                        setLocale("fr");
                        recreate();
                    })
                    .setCancelText(getString(R.string.cancel))
                    .setCancelClickListener(sweetAlertDialog -> sweetAlertDialog.cancel())
                    .show();

        });
    }

      private void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Resources res = this.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        config.locale = locale;
    } else {
        config.setLocale(locale);
    }
    res.updateConfiguration(config, dm);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("My_Lang", lang);
    editor.apply();

}

    public void LoadLocale() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String languge = prefs.getString("My_lang", "");
        setLocale(languge);
    }
}
```

"SweetAlertDialog" is the class that contains the custom Dialog.As the following :

```
public class SweetAlertDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String mTitleText;
    private String mContentText;
    private String mCancelText;
    private String mConfirmText;
    private OnSweetClickListener mCancelClickListener;
    private OnSweetClickListener mConfirmClickListener;
    @BindView(R.id.title_text)
    TextView titleTextView;
    @BindView(R.id.content_text)
    TextView contentTextView;
    @BindView(R.id.confirmbutton)
    Button confirmButton;
    @BindView(R.id.cancelbutton)
    Button cancelButton;

    public SweetAlertDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public interface OnSweetClickListener {
        void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        setTitleText(mTitleText);
        setContentText(mContentText);
        setCancelText(mCancelText);
        setConfirmText(mConfirmText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.cancelbutton) {
            if (mCancelClickListener != null) {
                mCancelClickListener.onClick(SweetAlertDialog.this);
            }else {
                dismiss();
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.confirmbutton) {
            if (mConfirmClickListener != null) {
                mConfirmClickListener.onClick(SweetAlertDialog.this);
            }else {
                dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        dismiss();
    }

    public SweetAlertDialog setCancelClickListener (OnSweetClickListener listener) {
        mCancelClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public SweetAlertDialog setConfirmClickListener (OnSweetClickListener listener) {
        mConfirmClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public SweetAlertDialog setTitleText(String text) {
        mTitleText = text;
        if (titleTextView != null && mTitleText != null) {
            titleTextView.setText(mTitleText);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public SweetAlertDialog setContentText(String text) {
        mContentText = text;
        if (contentTextView != null && mContentText != null) {
            contentTextView.setText(mContentText);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public SweetAlertDialog setConfirmText(String text) {
        mConfirmText = text;
        if (confirmButton != null && mConfirmText != null) {
            confirmButton.setText(mConfirmText);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public SweetAlertDialog setCancelText(String text) {
        mCancelText = text;
        if (mCancelText != null && cancelButton != null) {
            cancelButton.setText(mCancelText);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

My problem is when i click on "Yes", all the fields do not get translated.So, how to make my app working which all fields will be translated.

Comment: Are you sure you provided all the necessary translations in the strings.xml file in your values-fr folder?

Comment: yes, i put all the necessary translations in the strings.xml file in the values-fr folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case this code work, try it:

```
    private void changeApplicationLanguage(Locale locale) {
            Resources res = this.getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            // Set new language settings.
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) { 
                conf.local = local
            } else { 
                conf.setLocal(local)
            }
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            // Restart activity with new language settings.
            this.recreate();
        }
```

Comment: this code didn't work for me, could you please give me another solution

Comment: you tried it without `getBaseContext()` ? as I post it?

Comment: and you not create new configuration?

Comment: here's the new method :    private void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("My_Lang", lang);
        editor.apply();

    }

Comment: It not as I show, try to get configuration from resorses

Comment: and set to configuration via method setLocale()

Comment: These two ligne conf.setLocale(locale); conf.setLayoutDirection(locale); make an error "Call requires API level 17 (current min is 15): android.content.res.Configuration#setLayoutDirection "

Comment: yes api level for `config.locale = locale;` - 17 so you need to make like: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) { conf.local = local} else { config.setLocal(local)}`

Comment: i did as the following : private void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        changeApplicationLanguage(locale);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("My_Lang", lang);
        editor.apply();
    }
the app become black and don't run

Comment: I'm really stuck, could you please help me to find a solution

Comment: @MimiSoftware take a look my answer it different from your code!

Comment: @MimiSoftware try to change `Configuration config = new Configuration();` with `Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();`